# Error: Could not find or load main class Tool

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, spring-tool-suite

My configuration is below:

- Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T14:57:37+03:00)
- Maven home: `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/libexec`
- Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Java home: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`
- Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
- OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

I use Spring Tool Suite 3.7.1.RELEASE (Build Id: 201510041213).

I did all settings about Java, Maven and STS but when I try to run any Maven command, STS is throwing this exception, although it runs on terminal correctly.

Comment: 'I try to run any Maven command' how are you running it?

Comment: I am running any maven command in run as menu.

Comment: 1. try `right click on project` and `select Maven`--> `update project` (select the dependent project if there are any).     2. `Right click on pom.xml` and `run as maven clean`. 3. `Right click on pom.xml` and `run as maven install`

Comment: it doesn't work. i think, it is about system configuration, because i can run it on linux or windows with same configuration.

Comment: It looks like your JAVA_HOME is wrong should be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/` ... You should check on command line first. Just a simply `mvn --version` should work

Comment: my java_home environment is correct but maven's java home is $JAVA_HOME/jre. also, mvn commands for same project run on terminal correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a project that I had been developing on STS version 3.6.4.RELEASE, but when I downloaded STS 3.7.1.RELEASE on a different PC, imported the project and tried to build/clean/... with maven, it would show this error (`Error: Could not find or load main class Tool`) as well.

What I did was copy the version 3.6.4.RELEASE from one computer to the other computer, and then I could build the project. I then proceeded to update STS through eclipse rather than downloading from the site, and now I'm running 3.7.1.RELEASE on the second computer and the project continues to be able to launch now :)

AFAIK these were my steps then:

1. Get older version of STS (3.6.4.RELEASE in my case, that i had been using on a different pc,  copied it and deleted ini file because it caused an error at startup)
2. Import project
3. Update STS through eclipse
4. Maven now builds the project without errors

Hope this helps!